# Почему не срабатывает свойство IsBusy (WebBrowser)?

Tags: .net, webbrowser, c#

Вот такой код:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Lines[0]);
while (webBrowser1.IsBusy)
{
    MessageBox.Show("11");
}
```

Бокс с сообщением не вылазит. Хотя браузер грузит страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Lines[0]);
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    MessageBox.Show("11");
}
```

Работает. Но интересует, почему IsBusy не работает.